# selenium load chrome profile java

Tags: java, selenium, profile

I tried loading the chrome profile with selenium. However, whenever I upload the profile, I get an error:

```
invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use - user-data-dir.
```

```java
String chromeProfile = "C:\\Users\\ad\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
ChromeDriverService chSvc = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
   .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe")).usingAnyFreePort().build();
ChromeOptions chOption = new ChromeOptions();
chOption.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + chromeProfile);
chOption.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 33");
chOption.addArguments("--start-maximized");        
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chSvc, chOption);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run multiple instance of ChromeDriver with the same `user-data-dir`. What you can do is every time you create a ChromeDriver instance, create a temp directory then set it in ChromeOptions `chOption.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + tempDir);`